# Java generic hashmap return type for already created Hashmap

Tags: java

```
public class Demo1 {
    private HashMap<String, Student> studentMap;
    private HashMap<String, Teacher> teacherMap;

    Demo1(){
        intiate();
    }

    public void intiate() {
        studentMap = new HashMap<String, Student>();
        teacherMap = new HashMap<String, Teacher>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, Student> getStudentMap() {
        return studentMap;
    }

    public void setStudentMap(HashMap<String, Student> studentMap) {
        this.studentMap = studentMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Teacher> getTeacherMap() {
        return teacherMap;
    }

    public void setTeacherMap(HashMap<String, Teacher> teacherMap) {
        this.teacherMap = teacherMap;
    }

    //Genric HashMap
    public HashMap<String, Class<? extends Details>> getobject() 

        return ?;
    }
}
```

I have 2 hashmaps for Student and Teacher which are extenfing Details class.
I have 2 methods to return this hashmaps.
I want to create generic method to return any of this hashmap, if I provide only class name (Student or Teacher).
What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Had that been possible, you'd be able to add a `Student` to the hashmap of `Teacher`s (by getting it from that method), which would break type safety.

You can get a readonly version of such a map by returning `Map<String, ? extends YourBaseClass>`, which means exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: what would be return statement then ? Is it Map<String, ? extends YourBaseClass>

Comment: @SureshPhapale: You can return any value that matches that type.  I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
public <T extends Details> HashMap<String, T> getMap(Class<T> theClass);
```

Comment: You can, but you will have to put unchecked casts inside your method.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an interface (perhaps you'd call it Person) that both Student and Teacher implement. Then your method return type could be HashMap. Of course, if you want to call methods specific to Student or Teacher, you'll have to use casting.